# How can I solve the problem of you cannot assign number value to string value for inital state in React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I integrate typescript into my React application. I keep the initial state of the input element as an empty string. But the number value must be entered in this input. Typescript naturally says that you cannot assign a number value to the string value. How can I solve this problem, what is the conventional way of doing this? By the way, I didn't share the code because I thought it wasn't necessary to share it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, initialize those values to be `null`. By default, if the `strictNullChecks` is set to false Typescript allows you to set an initial value of `null`.

So this will not error: `val: number = null` and also is more readable in terms of your code intention.

With that being said, even if `strictNullChecks` is true in your settings, you could always assign an initial null value like with the non-null assertion opreator `!`, which tells Typescript that its ok the initial value is null and you will handle the assignment later yourself:

```
val: number = null!;
```

EDIT:

As suggested in the comments, you can also use [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html) like this: `val: number | string = ''`

Comment: Yes, I did that too, there is no problem on the typescript side. But react gives this error:  index.js:1 Warning: `value` prop on `input` should not be null. Consider using an empty string to clear the component or `undefined` for uncontrolled components.
    in input (at malzeme-listesi.tsx:226)

Comment: Gotcha. I'd use union type then: val: number | string = ''

Comment: Oh, I forgot we can do this in Typescript. Thanks for your help.

Comment: np, feel free to mark as accepted if helped